# Make a child element scrollable and fill parent's height

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In `web.telegram.com` web application, Most elements are fixed except for the contacts list and the chat area (It's scrollable and it fills its parent).

[image: a screenshot of telegram web application]

Now, I want to achieve this behavior with Bootstrap. My application has a fixed navbar, and a fixed-container which will hold the entire application. The application has multiple tabs. So I have fixed the tabs buttons to the top of that fixed-container. Finally there is an element which will hold the tabs themeselves.

You can check it here: http://www.bootply.com/3bO0UL9OHi

However, some tabs will contain a panel, with `header` and `footer`. I want to make them fixed to the top and the bottom of the tab container, and make the `panel-body`: fill the remaining area and be scrollable. Just like the chat area in the above telegram screenshot.

How could this be done? (using bootstrap, css, or jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using jQuery. It is not the best solution but it works at least.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#text-panel').parents().css('height', '100%');
  $('#text-panel').parents().css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
  // fix .fixed-container height. because it has `top: 70px;`.
  $('.fixed-container').css('height', $('.fixed-container').parent().outerHeight() - 70);
  // fix #main-tabs-panes height. because it should not have 100% of its parent.
  // the right value is: parent height - tabs-header height.
  $('#main-tabs-panes').css('height', $('#main-tabs-panes').parent().outerHeight() - $('#tabs-header').outerHeight());
  // now we set the height of our element.
  // it should be: parent height - panel header - panel footer - 20px.
  // because the panel has `margin-bottom: 20px`
  $('#text-panel').css('height', $('#text-panel').parent().outerHeight(true) - (20 + $('#text-panel').prev().outerHeight(true) + $('#text-panel').next().outerHeight(true)));
  $('#text-panel').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
});
$(window).resize();
```

So in general follow these steps:

1. Set all parents' height to '100%'.
2. Fix any parent with one of these: (`top`, `bottom`, `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`). Subtract their value.
3. Hide all `overflow-y`.
4. Set the height of your element. In my case it should be: (parent height MINUS all other siblings).
5. Set `overflow-y: auto`.

[Here is an updated version](http://www.bootply.com/O9vqj7Tpz1) (bootply)